# How to make casting video loop

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Is there anyway to make a video loop? I have the app working and the video streams but I want it to replay again as soon as it ends. Is there a simple option to add a loop option?

```
{
GCKMediaMetadata *metadata = [[GCKMediaMetadata alloc] init];

[metadata setString:@"Title" forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyTitle];

[metadata setString:@"www.website.com"

             forKey:kGCKMetadataKeySubtitle];

[metadata addImage:[[GCKImage alloc]
                    initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.website.com/thumbnail.png"]
                    width:480
                    height:360]];
// [END media-metadata]

// Define Media information.
// [START load-media]
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
[[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
 @"http://www.website.com/video.mp4"
                                    streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                   contentType:@"video/mp4"
                                      metadata:metadata
                                streamDuration:0
                                    customData:nil];

// Cast the video.
[_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:YES playPosition:0];
// [END load-media]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to build a queue of one item with the "repeat" flag turned on.

Comment: I don't see a repeat flag in the documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_queue_item.html

Comment: You set that flag when you are loading your queue, see queueLoadItems which takes a repeatMode parameter.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can implement it please. I'm new to this and i'm having trouble =/

Comment: If you look at the CastVideos-ios sample on our GitHub repo, you'll see example of how to set up a queue (of one element). All you have to add to that is to set the repeat flag.

Comment: Is the sample code inside the QueueTableViewController.m?

Comment: I'm looking at the sample iOS app but which view controller do I see the example in?

Comment: Can you please just lead me in the right direction and let me know which view controller in the sample project I should be looking at.

Comment: (1) Build a GCKMediaInformation first, (2) Build a GCKMediaQueueItem from that mediaInformation you just built, (3) load that queue (of one item) using queueLoadItems method of the class GCKMediaControlChannel. In the queueLoadItems method, you can set the repeatMode.

Comment: is there anyway to load a video to chromecast device but it would be downloaded just once instead of it downloading every time it repeats? I'm trying to save mobile data by only downloading once.

Comment: Chromecast devices have very limited space and you cannot "cache" videos there.